# Javascript: Eventhandler not functioning, works in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jsfiddle

So this is an answer to another question I posted and I think it is the correct solution. However, while it works wonderfully in jsfiddle it does not function whatsoever outside of that environment. I have tried multiple combinations and I cannot get this thing to work right.

I've tried `onLoad` in the body, `Window.onload` both in the header wrapping around the function and separately calling it at the base of the page after all the elements have loaded. Nothing works.

I always get this issue:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

Which is frustrating, because all other solutions to this error I have seen revolve around ensuring you do in fact have the specified ID the handler triggers off of in your HTML. Which I do.

I know its probably overkill to make a post here on this but I'm yanking my hair out.

Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fFW5r/1/

Here's a mockup page I made to test the concept (which never works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var link_container = document.getElementById('links');
    function myFunction(){ link_container.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
        if(e.target.nodeName === "A"){
            var href = e.target.getAttribute('href'),
                selfhost = window.location.hostname;
            if(href.indexOf(selfhost) !== -1){
                alert('Inbound link clicked');
            } else {
                alert('Outbound link clicked');
            }
        }
    }, false); 
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">

<div id="links">
    <a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/#foo">Inbound Link</a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Outbout Link</a>
</div>

<script>window.onload=myFunction()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This particular iteration I was trying to test it with the `onload` call at the bottom of the page after everything had loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var link_container = document.getElementById('links');` need to be executed on `document.onload` so it has to be inside `myFunction`

In jsfiddle, the code is executed on `load` by default. in the fiddle at the left side panel > second select box if you select `no wrap - in head` you can recreate the problem.
Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fFW5r/3/)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function myFunction(){ 
        var link_container = document.getElementById('links'); // <<-- Move it inside `myFunction()`
        link_container.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
        if(e.target.nodeName === "A"){
            var href = e.target.getAttribute('href'),
                selfhost = window.location.hostname;
            if(href.indexOf(selfhost) !== -1){
                alert('Inbound link clicked');
            } else {
                alert('Outbound link clicked');
            }
        }
    }, false); 

    }
</script>
```

Comment: See? I knew you guys would look at it and go "wow this is easy". Thanks a thousand Arun.

Now I have to wait 9min to accept your answer lol.

Comment: The element doesn't exist yet when you're running the script. The above answer should solve it.

Comment: @MichaelWatson: If you also want to access `link_container` in other functions outside this one too, simply wrap the whole script tag content in a `windows.onload(function(){})` That is also the reason why it works in the fiddle as jsFiddle by default (unless configured otherwise) wraps all the script tags in a `windows.onload` within the iframe anyway.

Comment: sigh, now it's not working on the page. I don't get any more errors on the console but it won't do anything when I select a link. This is for my production page (.cfm), my test page I made that I quoted up above (.html) works fine.

Comment: there are few test you can do, 1) add a console.log stmt at the begening of `myFunction` to see whether it is called, add `console.log(link_container.length, link_container)` after `var link_container = document.getElementById('links');` to see whether it returned anything

Comment: Nvm it's what the test page reads too with a console statement, except it executes properly.

Comment: it look fine, because it is a single element not an array

Comment: @MichaelWatson Can you add another console stmt in the click event handler just before `if(e.target.nodeName === "A"){`

Comment: I'm not getting anything off of that console statement. Console is entirely blank.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25857/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-michael-watson)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that you are initializing link_container before the DOM is ready. Then when myFunction() runs, link_container has been initialized to undefined. Which causes it to fail. Initializing it in the function (after the DOM has loaded) should fix the issue

Put declare link_container inside the function.

```
var link_container = document.getElementById('links');

function myFunction(){ 
    link_container.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
        if(e.target.nodeName === "A"){
            var href = e.target.getAttribute('href'),
                selfhost = window.location.hostname;
            if(href.indexOf(selfhost) !== -1){
                alert('Inbound link clicked');
            } else {
                alert('Outbound link clicked');
            }
        }
    }, false); 
}
```